# Xml being deserialized into base class instead of derived classes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I know this is a popular topic and I have researched extensively without finding an answer to my problem.

I have a base class `IntroductionAction` and 2 derived classes `IntroductionActionComplex` and `IntroductionActionSimple`. I have a list of `IntroductionAction` objects to which I have added objects of both of the derived types. My classes are as follows:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(IntroductionActionComplex))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(IntroductionActionSimple))]
public class IntroductionAction
{
    public IntroductionAction() { }
}

public class IntroductionActionComplex : IntroductionAction
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "QuestionString")]
    public string question { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AnswerString")]
    public List<string> answerStrings { get; set; }

    public IntroductionActionComplex()
    {
        name = string.Empty;
        question = null;
        answerStrings = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class IntroductionActionSimple : IntroductionAction
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IntroductionActionSimple()
    {
        Value = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I then create the List as follows

```
[XmlElement("IntroductionAction")]
public List<IntroductionAction> introductionActions { get; set; }
```

I am using `XmlSerializer` and everything serializes correctly. This is the resulting XML of the list containing one of each of the derived classes which is correct.

```
<IntroductionAction>
  <QuestionString>
    test
  </QuestionString>
  <AnswerString>
    test
  </AnswerString>
  <AnswerString>
    test
  </AnswerString>
</IntroductionAction>
<IntroductionAction>
  test
</IntroductionAction>
```

This XML file is going onto a device which doesn't read it as XML but just searches for the tags and does whatever work it needs to do and because of that the file can't contain any XSI or XSD tags, indentation, etc that is usually associated with proper XML.

My deserialization code is straight forward:

```
public static T Deserialize_xml_Config<T>(string file1, T obj)
{
   XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
   using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file1))
   {
      return (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
   }
}
```

Finally to my problem. When I deserialize, it is being deserialized to the base class `IntroductionAction` and not to the derived classes.
These `IntroductionAction` classes are just part of a much larger object that I am serializing/deserializing. I have tried making the base class abstract since it contains no functionality but I get an error on deserialization saying

> The specified type is abstract: name='IntroductionAction'

Despite my XmlIncludes it seems unable to find the derived classes.

I have tried adding the types to the serializer but that didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:
This is what I mean by adding the types to the serializer

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), new Type [] { typeof(IntroductionActionComplex), typeof(IntroductionActionSimple) });
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file1))
{
   return (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Also my attempt at using `XmlAttributeOverrides`:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var attrs = new XmlAttributes();
XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute();
attr.ElementName = "IntroductionAction";
attr.Type = typeof(IntroductionActionComplex);
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);
attr.ElementName = "IntroductionAction";
attr.Type = typeof(IntroductionActionSimple);
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);
attrOverrides.Add(typeof(IntroductionAction), "IntroductionAction", attrs);

XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), attrOverrides);
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file1))
{
   return (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Add above every class a [XmlRoot(ElementName = "......")] with the actual tag name (it is upper/lower case sensitive) to specify which class you want each tag to go into.

Comment: Can you post what you did for `I have tried adding the types to the serializer but that didnt work`?  I believe you'll need to override the xml attributes, but I want to see what you did first.

Comment: @jdweng pretty sure that won't work though because both the derived objects have to come under the same tag name i.e <IntroductionAction>

Comment: Your XML was not generated correctly -- there should be an [`xsi:type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx) attribute on each `<IntroductionAction>` element to specify the type, e.g. `<IntroductionAction xsi:type="IntroductionActionComplex">`.  How did you generate the XML?  If I serialize your classes with `XmlSerializer` the type information is present.

Comment: @dbc I had to override the TextWriter to remove those tags as they can't be present in the file. That is outside of my control it's just the way it has to be. I have tested it with those type tags present and everything works correctly so it only becomes an issue when they are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close.  Below is the full example of saving and loading the XML file based on derived class types.  This will save the nodes as the derived type itself, so loading back in will keep the desired type, rather than convert back to the base type.  You'll probably need to add exception handling, this was just a quick solution.  I did not change your base `IntroductionAction` or the derived `IntroductionActionComplex` / `IntroductionActionSimple` classes.

```
public class RootNode
{
   [XmlElement("IntroductionAction")]
   public List<IntroductionAction> introductionActions { get; set; }

   public RootNode()
   {
      introductionActions = new List<IntroductionAction>();
   }

   private static XmlAttributeOverrides GetXmlAttributeOverrides()
   {
      XmlAttributeOverrides xml_attr_overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
      XmlAttributes xml_attrs = new XmlAttributes();
      xml_attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(IntroductionActionComplex)));
      xml_attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(typeof(IntroductionActionSimple)));
      xml_attr_overrides.Add(typeof(RootNode), "introductionActions", xml_attrs);
      return xml_attr_overrides;
   }

   // Add exception handling
   public static void SaveToFile(RootNode rootNode, string fileName)
   {
      using (MemoryStream mem_stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(rootNode.GetType(), RootNode.GetXmlAttributeOverrides());
         serializer.Serialize(mem_stream, rootNode);

         using (BinaryWriter output = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
         {
            output.Write(mem_stream.ToArray());
         }
      }
   }

   // Add exception handling
   public static RootNode LoadFromFile(string fileName)
   {
      if (File.Exists(fileName))
      {
         using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
         {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
               XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootNode), RootNode.GetXmlAttributeOverrides());
               return (RootNode)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Test program:

```
internal class Program
{
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      RootNode obj = new RootNode();
      obj.introductionActions.Add(new IntroductionActionComplex() { question = "qTest", answerStrings = { "aTest1", "aTest2" }, name = "aName1" });
      obj.introductionActions.Add(new IntroductionActionSimple() { name = "aName2", Value = "aValue" });

      RootNode.SaveToFile(obj, "Test.xml");

      RootNode obj2 = RootNode.LoadFromFile("Test.xml");
   }
}
```

Comment: In the GetXmlAttributeOverrides() function above you have typeof(RootNode) when adding to  xml_attr_overrides. Is that referring to the class in which the introductionActions list was created and initialized yeah?

Comment: @M.Geaney - Yes. If you wanted the nodes in the XML to be all `IntroductionAction` instead of the derived class names, you could change it to `typeof(IntroductionAction)` and the xml will tag each node with its type.  The XML becomes more verbose and a little less clear in my opinion, but its another option.

Comment: I gave it a go but no luck. It is still deserializing into 2 base class IntroductionAction objects instead of the IntroductionActionComplex and IntroductionActionSimple objects.